# How to connect my label object to a cell using nibs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

this is a basic question I know but i'm a newbie so if you don't mind I will ask it anyway.

I'v created a custom UITableViewCell class, and dragged a label from the object inspector to it:

[image]

Now I know that I need to connect this label to the files owner or something like this right?

So what I though is to click on the label, go to the connections inspector and drag an outlet to the label:

[image]

[image]

What do I need to select from the selection box that came up...is that right? please correct me if i did something wrong..thanks ahead!

Comment: You need an `IBOutlet` on your code side UILabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a variable UILabel in your cell.h then the name of this variable will appear in the list.